# STM32F723 : correct connection for VDD12OTGHS pi

Tags: usb, stm32

I'm currently designing a PCB for my caving robot.
Initially, I wanted to use a STM32F722ZET6, but as it is currently out of stock, I'm switching for a STM32F72**3**ZET6.

There are a few pins displaced, and 2 GPIOs that are replaced by 2 "special pins" : VDD12OTGHS and OTG_HS_REXT.

For those, I'm not totally sure what I need to do (knowing that I will not use USB OTG on this project, but that I will use nearly all GPIOs).

From the [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f723ze.pdf) (p30) and the [application note on hardware development of STM32F7](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an4661-getting-started-with-stm32f7-series-mcu-hardware-development-stmicroelectronics.pdf) (p8), I have to connect a 2.2µF capacitor between pin VDD12OTGHS and ground.

From what I understand, I'm NOT to connect this pin to a supply, even if the name starts with VDD : do you confirm?

For the OTG_HS_REXT pin, I have to connect a 3k 1% resistor between the pin and ground : correct? (cf app note, page 8) Do I still need it (and with 1% accuracy) if not using USB OTG?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From what I understand, I'm NOT to connect this pin to a supply, even
> if the name starts with VDD : do you confirm?

Yes, the 2.2uf Cap is for a bypass cap for a voltage regulator for the USB PHY, which needs 1.2V. There is nothing in the documentation (that I saw anyway) that suggests that the regulator can be turned off.

This diagram on figure 29 should prove useful:

[image]
Source: https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f723ze.pdf